# Rendering segmented button as a grid

Tags: sapui5

OpenUI5 control sap.ui.commons.SegementedButton renders group of buttons in a single line. How to render these buttons of a SegementedButton into a grid (mostly 3 x 7) rather than a single line ?

```
new sap.ui.commons.SegmentedButton({
buttons:
[
new sap.ui.commons.Button({id:"b1",height:"3em",width:"3%",text:"1"}),
new sap.ui.commons.Button({id:"b2",height:"3em",width:"3%",text:"2"}),
new sap.ui.commons.Button({id:"b3",height:"3em",width:"3%",text:"3"}),
new sap.ui.commons.Button({id:"b4",height:"3em",width:"3%",text:"4"}),
new sap.ui.commons.Button({id:"b5",height:"3em",width:"3%",text:"5"}),
new sap.ui.commons.Button({id:"b6",height:"3em",width:"3%",text:"6"}),
new sap.ui.commons.Button({id:"b7",height:"3em",width:"3%",text:"7"}),
new sap.ui.commons.Button({id:"b8",height:"3em",width:"3%",text:"8"}),
new sap.ui.commons.Button({id:"b22",height:"3em",width:"5%", text:"9"})
select:function(oEvent) {
alert("Selected button id: "+oEvent.getParameters().selectedButtonId);}
})
```

Comment: Guess you will need a custom control or at least extensive custom styling here.

Comment: why dont you use a control which is more useful for this? Like a grid?! :D I think segmented button is not the right to apply an grid. you can uses Tiles or sap.ui.layout.Grid to define an 3x7 grid, simple add the buttons where you want them in the grid? Even a matrix layout would be able to handle this grid-layouting... see e.g. https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.GridTasks/preview

Comment: This is a cross post from SCN: http://scn.sap.com/message/15804135#15804135
When cross-posting, please mention that. People might put time into answering your question while it might have already been answered on SCN. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: zyrex - requirement is to be able to select a single button at any given time in the SegmentedButton. If I have to go with a Grid, I will have to write custom logic for this requirement. SegmentedButton is close to my requirement except that it displays buttons in a single line and I need it as a grid